# Shared options and flags between commands

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Say my CLI utility has three commands: `cmd1`, `cmd2`, `cmd3`

And I want `cmd3` to have same options and flags as `cmd1` and `cmd2`. Like some sort of inheritance.

```
@click.command()
@click.options("--verbose")
def cmd1():
    pass

@click.command()
@click.options("--directory")
def cmd2():
    pass

@click.command()
@click.inherit(cmd1, cmd2) # HYPOTHETICAL
def cmd3():
    pass
```

So `cmd3` will have flag `--verbose` and option `--directory`. Is it possible to make this with Click? Maybe I just have overlooked something in the documentation...

**EDIT:** I know that I can do this with `click.group()`. But then all the group's options must be specified before group's command. I want to have all the options normally after command.

`cli.py --verbose --directory /tmp cmd3` -> `cli.py cmd3 --verbose --directory /tmp`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have found a simple solution! I slightly edited the snippet from https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/108 :

```
import click


_cmd1_options = [
    click.option('--cmd1-opt')
]

_cmd2_options = [
    click.option('--cmd2-opt')
]


def add_options(options):
    def _add_options(func):
        for option in reversed(options):
            func = option(func)
        return func
    return _add_options


@click.group()
def group(**kwargs):
    pass


@group.command()
@add_options(_cmd1_options)
def cmd1(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


@group.command()
@add_options(_cmd2_options)
def cmd2(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


@group.command()
@add_options(_cmd1_options)
@add_options(_cmd2_options)
@click.option("--cmd3-opt")
def cmd3(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    group()
```

Comment: Kickass solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 34):

Define a class with common parameters

```
class StdCommand(click.core.Command):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.params.insert(0, click.core.Option(('--default-option',), help='Every command should have one'))
```

Then pass the class to decorator when defining the command function

```
@click.command(cls=StdCommand)
@click.option('--other')
def main(default_option, other):
  ...
```

Comment: This the cleanest and most elegant solution. Works without a hitch.

I suggests replacing `click.core.Command` with `click.Command`. Don't really need to go to the lower module. Also, it is cleaner to say `self.params = [...]` instead of inserting to an empty list.

Comment: @d0m1n0 First comment is absolutely correct, but the second - isn't. The list is not necessarily empty, you overwrite what's in it with the proposed approach. When you add more options (the `--other`), they're gone.

Answer (score 11):

You could also have another decorator for shared options. I found this solution [here](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/108)

```py
def common_params(func):
    @click.option('--foo')
    @click.option('--bar')
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@click.command()
@common_params
@click.option('--baz')
def cli(foo, bar, baz):
    print(foo, bar, baz)
```

Answer (score 4):

This code extracts all the options from it's arguments

```
def extract_params(*args):
    from click import Command
    if len(args) == 0:
        return ['']
    if any([ not isinstance(a, Command) for a in args ]):
        raise TypeError('Handles only Command instances')

    params = [ p.opts() for cmd_inst in args for p in cmd_inst.params ]
    return list(set(params))
```

now you can use it:

```
@click.command()
@click.option(extract_params(cmd1, cmd2))
def cmd3():
    pass
```

This code extracts only the parameters and none of their default values, you can improve it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Options in `click` are decorator factories, and can be reused like so:

```py
import sys
import click


verbose = click.option("--verbose")
directory = click.option("--directory")


@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    pass


@cli.command()
@verbose
def cmd1(verbose):
    print(f'Running cmd1: {verbose = }')


@cli.command()
@directory
def cmd2(directory):
    print(f'Running cmd2: {directory = }')


@cli.command()
@verbose
@directory
@click.option('--baz')
def cmd3(verbose, directory, baz):
    print(f'Running cmd3: {verbose = }, {directory = }, {baz = }')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(cli())
```

Having saved this file as `app.py`, you can test with:

```bash
> python app.py cmd1 --verbose=1
# Running cmd1: verbose = '1'
```

```bash
> python app.py cmd2 --directory='.'
# Running cmd2: directory = '.'
```

```bash
> python app.py cmd3 --verbose=1 --directory='.'
# Running cmd3: verbose = '1', directory = '.', baz = None
```

However,

```bash
python app.py cmd2 --verbose=1
```

```
Usage: app.py cmd2 [OPTIONS]
Try 'app.py cmd2 --help' for help.

Error: No such option: --verbose
```

Don't forget that using `@` for decorators in python is just a syntactic shortcut for an explicit call to the decorator, passing the function as the first parameter and returning another function. You can just assign that function to a variable, and `click` allows you to reuse them as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement on @jirinovo solution.
this version support an unlimited number of click options.
one thing that is worth mentioning, the order you pass the options is important

```py
import click

_global_options = [click.option('--foo', '-f')]
_local_options = [click.option('--bar', '-b', required=True)]
_local_options2 = [click.option('--foofoo', required=True)]


def add_options(*args):
    def _add_options(func):
        options = [x for n in args for x in n]
        for option in reversed(options):
            func = option(func)
        return func

    return _add_options


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.group()
def subcommand():
    pass


@subcommand.command()
@add_options(_global_options, _local_options)
def echo(foo, bar):
    print(foo, bar, sep='\n')


@subcommand.command()
@add_options(_global_options)
def echo2(foo):
    print(foo)


@subcommand.command()
@add_options(_global_options, _local_options2)
def echo3(foo, foofoo):
    print(foo, foofoo, sep='\n')


@subcommand.command()
@add_options(_global_options, _local_options, _local_options2)
def echo4(foo, bar, foofoo):
    print(foo, bar, foofoo, sep='\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```